# Allegro não executa nada gráfico

Tags: c, allegro

Ele simplesmente não aparece nada gráfico, o funcional (fechar a janela) funciona perfeitamente, porém o gráfico (cor de fundo e a "nave") não funcionam.

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include "objetos.h"

const int height = 800;
const int width = 600;

void InitNave(NaveEspacial &nave);
void DesenhaNave(NaveEspacial &nave);


int main(void)
{
        ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
        ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *fila_eventos = NULL;

        bool end = false;

        NaveEspacial nave;

        if(!al_init())
        {
                al_show_native_message_box(NULL, "AVISO!", NULL, "FALHA AO CARREGAR ALLEGRO", NULL, NULL);
                return -1;
        }

        display = al_create_display(height, width);

        al_init_primitives_addon();

        fila_eventos = al_create_event_queue();

        al_register_event_source(fila_eventos, al_get_display_event_source(display));

        if(!display)
        {
                al_show_native_message_box(NULL, "AVISO!", NULL, "FALHA AO CARREGAR O DISPLAY", NULL, NULL);
                return -1;
        }

        InitNave(nave);

        while(!end)
        {
                ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
                al_wait_for_event(fila_eventos, &ev);

                if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
                {
                        end = true;
                }

                DesenhaNave(nave);

                al_flip_display;
                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
        }

        al_destroy_display(display);
        al_destroy_event_queue(fila_eventos);

        return 0;
}

void InitNave(NaveEspacial &nave)
{
        nave.x = 20;
        nave.y = height / 2;
        nave.ID = JOGADOR;
        nave.vidas = 3;
        nave.velocidade = 7;
        nave.borda_x = 6;
        nave.borda_y = 7;
        nave.pontos = 0;
}
void DesenhaNave(NaveEspacial &nave)
{
        al_draw_filled_rectangle(nave.x, nave.y - 9, nave.x + 10, nave.y - 7, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0));
        al_draw_filled_rectangle(nave.x, nave.y + 9, nave.x + 10, nave.y + 7, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0));
        al_draw_filled_triangle(nave.x - 12, nave.y - 17, nave.x + 12, nave.y, nave.x - 12, nave.y + 17, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0));
        al_draw_filled_rectangle(nave.x - 12, nave.y - 2, nave.x + 15 , nave.y + 2, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 255));
}
```

Comment: Me parece que você inverteu a largura com a altura. A sua lógica dentro do `while` está esquisita, pois me parece que isso significa que ele só irá desenhar quando receber algum evento, inclusive o evento de fechamento. Aliás, o que há no `"objetos.h"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esqueceu os parênteses no al_flip_display(). Sendo assim, o display nunca será atualizado a cada iteração (E você nunca verá a nave (Nem nada)).

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Comment: De nada :). Me adiciona aí depois (Meu Facebook está no meu perfil aqui do stack). Também desenvolvo com Allegro, e estou criando uma engine em C++ para ele.